# Can I give prefixes to some actors' automatic names?

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I have some Akka project and I have the following scenario: I have plenty of actors for which I would like to have a human-readable name, but at the same time, I don't want to generate unique names for each one by myself. So, is there a way so I can tell to the props or the actor system to prefix the automatically-generated name with a specific string?

For example, I have some actor Master who creates some children of type Worker. I would like that the name of each children starts by "worker-" so I can follow easily in the logs. Also, if possible, I would like to know if there are other ways to name the actors in a more fine-grained fashion.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: this is an example of what I would like to have

Currently, you have two options, a far as I can see:

1) Create the actor with the automatically generated name

```
ActorRef myActor = mySystem.actorOf(MyActor.props());
```

2) Create the actor with a user-specified name

```
ActorRef myActor = mySystem.actorOf( MyActor.props(), MyNamingAPI.getSomeNewName() );
```

1) is bad because in the logs I don't know who is who. 2) is bad because I have to write/use my own API and because if someone else uses my actor project as subsystem, he will have to be careful to not repeat the names or use a different actor system. So, it's not portable.

I would like if Akka supported something like:

```
ActorRef myActor = mySystem.actorOf(MyActor.props(), "my-actor-%");
```

where the % symbol denotes the automatically generated ID.

Comment: Sadly, this is not supported in the API. Without generating the names yourself or using an API that does the generation under the hood, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @VinceEmigh mentioned in the comments, this is not supported by the API. Moreover, Akka team have no plans to support it any soon (or at all). More on this [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16613).

Answer (score -1):

See if something like the following will work. Basically you can pass a seq number to your worker actors when you create them. That way you can relate back to them.

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem, Actor}


object ActorNaming extends App {

  implicit val actorSys = ActorSystem("NameDemoAS")

  val master = actorSys.actorOf(Props[Master], "my-name-is-master")
  master ! "name"

  (1 to 10).map{ i => actorSys.actorOf(Props[Worker], s"my-name-is-worker-$i")}.map{ actor => actor ! "name"}

}


class Master extends Actor {

  def receive : Receive = {
    case "name" => println(context.self.path.name)
  }
}

class Worker extends Actor {
  def receive : Receive = {
    case "name" => println(context.self.path.name)
  }
}
```

The output is

```
my-name-is-master
my-name-is-worker-1
my-name-is-worker-2
my-name-is-worker-7
my-name-is-worker-3
my-name-is-worker-4
my-name-is-worker-8
my-name-is-worker-5
my-name-is-worker-6
my-name-is-worker-9
my-name-is-worker-10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Certainly works, but in my question I said that "I don't want to generate unique names for each one by myself". The possibilities for generating unique names are infinite, and the boilerplate is not really important, since you will only write it once and reuse it. My question was if there isn't a neat way supported by the API.

Comment: Oh okay. Can you provide an example (pseudo code) of what kind of API would like to see for generating names. But do you think something like this should be part of the standard API? Do you want the names to be completely random? IMO, the naming can be a highly context specific and domain driven.

Comment: "I don't want to generate unique names for each one by myself" - Are you creating these actors yourself or not?

Comment: I'm creating these actors myself, yes. I edited the question to include an example of what I would like. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I think your question is much more clear now.